# Is there SSO(single sign-on) available for twitter android?

Tags: android, twitter

I was implementing social sharing for my app. I did for facebook and there was SSO was available. But for twitter, it was not available. I searched and didn't find any. Any help Please!!!!

Comment: Is it possible you mean oAuth, not SSO?

Comment: What Facebook calls SSO is basically OAuth. It's even called OAuth in the source code of the samples. Twitters OAuth authentication is [well documented](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth).

Comment: Thanks for correcting me.....I haven't read it just wanted to ask is it there to check if user is signed in in twitter app ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [fabric's twitter API](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html)

Comment: but i don't want to use twitter login button.